# Send json body to GET Method in angular 8

Tags: angular, api

One of my client build his API and in which he have Get API call.
As per his API development, I need to sent JSON as a body (Not a query params) to GET method.

I tried all possible methods but failed to achieve the result.

```
let httpParams = new HttpParams()
        .set('loginid', 'admin')
        .set('password', '123');
```

doing something like this not working because its build query param while api call.

```
return this.http.get<{}>(apiUrl, { params: postParam });
```

Any help will be life-saving.

Comment: Tell your client to build an API that respects the HTTP protocol: GET requests don't have a body.

Answer (score 0):

Only POS, PUT, PATCH requests allowed body.

```
return this.http.post<{}>(apiUrl, { login: 'admin', password: '123' });
```